# How to get months and remaining days between two dates (i.e. start and end date)

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to crack a logic but no luck till now. Need your support to resolve the problem. I need to calculate the # of days occurring in a month between Start and End Date.

To explain in detail, following is the input structure:

> ID|Start Date|End Date
>
> 1 |15-Jan-16 |15-Feb-16
>
> 2 |23-Jan-16 |15-Mar-16

From the above form, the application calculates the number of days occurring in a particular month. e.g. for ID=1, Jan has 16 days and Feb has 14 days. The form is translated into following output:

> ID | Month | Days
>
> 1  | Jan   | 16
>
> 1  | Feb   | 14
>
> 2  | Jan   | 8
>
> 2  | Feb   | 29
>
> 2  | Mar   | 13

Is there any way the above can be done?

Comment: This reads like a homework question. What have you tried so far. Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use this to represent a time interval in days, hours or even minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the results you gave in your question is incorrect, but this is how you can do it:

```
var obj = new[] {
    new { ID=1, StartDate=new DateTime(2016,1,15), EndDate=new DateTime(2016,2,15) },
    new { ID=2, StartDate=new DateTime(2016,1,23), EndDate=new DateTime(2016,3,15) }
};

var result=obj.SelectMany(x=>
    Enumerable.Range(0,int.MaxValue)
        .Select(m=>new DateTime(x.StartDate.Year,x.StartDate.Month,1).AddMonths(m))
        .TakeWhile(m=>m<x.EndDate)
        .Select(m=>new {
            x.ID,
            //m.Year,
            Month=m.ToString("MMM"),
            Days=(x.EndDate.Year==m.Year && x.EndDate.Month==m.Month?x.EndDate.Day:DateTime.DaysInMonth(m.Year,m.Month))
            -(x.StartDate.Year==m.Year && x.StartDate.Month==m.Month?x.StartDate.Day:0)
        })
);
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that your question did not specify how you wanted to handle the situation where the time span between StartDate and EndDate is longer than a year.  My code keeps the months separate, but it would be trivial to combine multiple years' months into a single `Days` value if that is what you need instead.  The answer also ignores whether `EndDate` is inclusive or exclusive since your sample data is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the field, and then parse the dates, like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(text, 
   "dd-MMM-yy", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
   DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Then loop from the initial date to the last date. I suggest using the first day of the start date to the first day of the last date for the loop (otherwise the last month could not be executed if the day of the first month is greater than the day of the last month). To increment, use AddMonth(1) method. You can get the number of days in each month with `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)`.

For the first month, subtract the day of the first date from the days in the month.

For the last month, subtract 1 from the day of the last date.

For the other months, just pick the days in month.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it using a little helper method:

```
var data = ranges
    .SelectMany(r => GetMonthlyDates(r.From, r.To)
        .Select(m => new
        {
            r.ID,
            MonthName = m.ToString("MMM"),
            Days = m.Year == r.From.Year && m.Month == r.From.Month
                ? DateTime.DaysInMonth(m.Year, m.Month) - m.Day
                : (m.Year == r.To.Year && m.Month == r.To.Month ? r.To.Day : DateTime.DaysInMonth(m.Year, m.Month))
        }));

private static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonthlyDates(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    for (DateTime current = from; current.Year < to.Year || current.Month <= to.Month; current = current.AddMonths(1))
        yield return current;
}
```

Which gives me:

```
1 | Jan | 16
1 | Feb | 15
2 | Jan | 8
2 | Feb | 29
2 | Mar | 15
```